# using ajax in asp.net without update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am from LAMP Background and started my venture into asp.net. Ive been amazed at the ease of ajax use using update panel. But then i started to read about all the over heads in it. So now i am trying to find a better way to implement ajax even if it means going back all the way to how we do it in the PHP world, using jquery to send a request with some parameters and then populate the container with the new data. But i am stumped on how to do it the right way in asp.net.

If some one can point me in the right direction on what is the correct way to implement ajax in asp.net with some links it d be great.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this post will help you.
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/